# Google Dart Core Pages Clear Children

Tags: javascript, tabs, dart, counter, polymer

I'm attempting to clear the children elements on a page whenever a page is changed.  However, with the current method of doing so, nothing on the page always changes, the same properties remain.  Right now, I have dynamically generated inputs that have different data in them depending on which tab is selected and displays the appropriate core-page (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-pages).  Is there a way to reset the core-page each time so that the different inputs for each tab will show up appropriately?  The children.clear() may not be the best approach. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
 @observable int pageChangeCount = 1;

 void pageChanged(oldValue, newValue) {

    var pages = document.querySelector('core-pages');
    pageChangeCount++;
    if (page == 0) {


      if(pageChangeCount %2 != 0)
      {
      pages.children.clear();
      }

      Display(true);

    } else if (page == 1) {


      if(pageChangeCount %2 == 0)
      {
      pages.children.clear();
      }

      Display(false);

    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it by going through all of the elements:

```
 pages.children.removeWhere( (Element e) {
      if( e.nodeName != "ELEMENT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR") {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
```